# Error when booting clonezilla

Tags: boot, clonezilla

I've put a clonezilla boot image on a usbdrive then when I boot Clonezilla I get the below screen then Clonzezilla opens normally. I wonder if this will affect my clone process?

[image]

Comment: How did you put the image on the USB drive?

Comment: @RamanSailopal using Tuxboot

Answer (score 0):

No, in my opinion it's totally fine.

You won't need a TPM (trusted platform module) for cloning.

Neither does the cache help you cloning.

So you'll be fine :)

(Proof: I get the same errors as you do an my cloning works)